# Cannot evaluate constraint(s) at starting point

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex, neos-server

I am using MINLP with NEOS solver, my problem is non-convex and I get this

```
Cannot evaluate constraint(s) at starting point
```

what does this mean and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning is rather obvious. The functions in your constraints cannot be evaluated at the starting point. If the starting point is zero and you have `log(x-0.5)` in the model you may get a message like this.

The fix is to provide better bounds and a better initial point. How to specify this depends on how you created the model and what modeling tools were used.

Comment: thank you, yes my constraints are not defined at 0, so how I can remove 0?

Comment: but at zero I have 0/0 is it problem?

Comment: x/y can often be protected either setting a lower bound on y (e.g. y>=0.001) or by multiplying expressions by y or by doing something like x/(y+0.0001).

Comment: I will try x/(y+0.0001) hopefully not change my problem. and I have very complicate case than x/y